# Discord Increment Not Functioning

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to implement a function/code in Discord.js Python, where every time a user in the server mentions a word in an array, it will increment the function by one. Therefore, the bot can count how many times a group of words has been said in the server. However, I keep running into an issue where the function would not increment at all, and it would always simply print out '1'.

```
import discord;
import os
import requests
import json
import random


client = discord.Client()

word = [ hello, hi, thanks, good ]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    msg = message.content

    if message.content.startswith('$commands'):
      await message.channel.send('$stats')
      await message.channel.send('$counter')
      await message.channel.send('$address')
      await message.channel.send('$csgo')
      await message.channel.send('$cpicture')

      
    if message.content.startswith('$counter'):
      increment = 0
      increment += 1
      print(increment)
      any(word in msg for word in word)
      await message.channel.send('This server has said the word ')
      await message.channel.send(increment)
      await message.channel.send(' times.')
  
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

os.environ['TOKEN']
```

Comment: "increment = 0" followed by "increment = 1".  It appears that you're setting it to zero every time, and then incrementing 0 to the value of 1. I'd try moving the "increment=0" to another location so it doesn't reset every time

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below, which has three changes made to it. Let me know if it helped solve the problem. See the code comments for what changes were made.

```
import discord;
import os
import requests
import json
import random


client = discord.Client()
word = [ hello, hi, thanks, good ]
increment=0; #Try adding here to global scope

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global increment #Get a reference to the global variable above
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    msg = message.content

    if message.content.startswith('$commands'):
      await message.channel.send('$stats')
      await message.channel.send('$counter')
      await message.channel.send('$address')
      await message.channel.send('$csgo')
      await message.channel.send('$cpicture')

    if message.content.startswith('$counter'):
      #increment = 0 (Remove this to prevent resetting)
      increment += 1
      print(increment)
       any(word in msg for word in word)
      await message.channel.send('This server has said the word ')
      await message.channel.send(increment)
      await message.channel.send(' times.')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

os.environ['TOKEN']
```